# For the following View, is it better to use one or two RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout

What my Activity is supposed to look like is:

__

TextView (i.e. heading for the activity, ***exactly 1***)

__

TextView

TextView

TextView

... (***arbitrary length***, i.e. body of the article with newlines separating the TextView) **However, at most at the beginning, only probably 5 lines of TextView are shown, and at the bottom of these TextView, there is a Read More button, so this would involve a Expandable RecyclerView Item (not sure how to implement that)**

***| Read More button |***

__

LinearLayout (with Buttons such as comment, like, dislike, etc, ***exactly 1***) **This LinearLayout is interesting too. I want it to become a sticky footer, so only when the above RecyclerView of TextViews height exceeds the screen will this LinearLayout stick to the bottom of the screen, otherwise it is attached to the bottom of the last TextView above**

__

RelativeLayout (custom layout for the comments including ImageView, TextView etc)

RelativeLayout

RelativeLayout

... (***arbitrary length*** depending on how many comments, ***minimum 0***)

__

I'm not sure if I should put all this in ONE RecyclerView with multiple viewholders (one for the TextView, one for the LinearLayout, one for the comment RelativeLayout)

OR

If I should split it into two RecyclerView, with the LinearLayout and the first TextView not being part of the RecyclerView (since I know there are only one of them).

All of the data from this Activity come from one API call. The first TextView is the title of the article, second is a list of TextView is the body, third is LinearLayout with action buttons for the article, lastly are the comments. **There are no interdependency between the first list of TextView and the latter list of RelativeLayout**

**Update**

Comment: Its better to go with **RecyclerView**. You can use sticky header as **Item Decorations in RecyclerView**. And for **show more option** - First set the size to 5 items and when clicks on show more refresh the size and notify the adapter.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you'd like to show the lists on screen. If both lists should be visible at the same time - use two `RecyclerView`s, if only one (you need to scroll down to reach the second list) - then use only one `RecyclerView`.

Also if you will go with only one `RecyclerView`, make view layouts as similar as possible, e.g. wrap `TextView` inside `RelativeLayout` for the first list as well and hide/show only the content of the `RelativeLayout` inside `onBindViewHolder` method.